# How to get the data between last two brackets in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help me to get data between last brackets. Here are two example strings:

```
This (is) jquery (Application) and Output: Application   
This (is) jquery (Application) with bootstrap (css) and Output: css
```

I tried the below code

```
var str = "This (is) jquery (Application)"; pos = str.indexOf("(") + 1; 
str = str.slice(pos, str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

I am getting the value between the first `(` and last `)`. How can I get the value between the last two brackets?

Comment: You are getting the first `(` because that is what your code says to do. Take a closer look!

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the last index of `(` and last index of `)`

```
pos = str.lastIndexOf("(") + 1; str = str.slice(pos, str.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/c520vmoe/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to get the matches string and use the last one as result:

```
Regex.Matches("(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))", "This (is) jquery (Application)")
```

It will return `is` and `Application`. Then you can take the second one as result.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5TJqAd/1